# make object from two arrays with the seperate arrays as properties

Tags: php, arrays

I have a `PHP` function that give me two seperate JSON arrays (array1 and array2). How can I merge them in an object with properties, like this:

```
{
  "array1": [ {"type": "column", "valueField": ..., "descriptionField": ..., }]
  "array2": [ {"type": "column", "valueField": ..., "descriptionField": ..., }] 
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Show us your code, what do you want as a result? What are you getting as a result with your try. Also, you should take a read for [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `$result = "[$array1, $array2]";` maybe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a simple example of how you can do it, you can improve it however you like, depending what kind of situation you need it for.

```
// Initialising arrays
$array1 = ['type' => 'column', 'valueField' => '.1.', 'descriptionField' =>  '.11.'];
$array2 = ['type' => 'column', 'valueField' => '.2.', 'descriptionField' =>  '.22.'];

// Turn them manually into jsons
$obj1 = json_encode($array1);
$obj2 = json_encode($array2);

// Merge the two jsonified arrays in a single array with whichever keys you prefer
$mix = ['array1' => $obj1, 'array2' => $obj2];

// Turn the merged "mix" array into json
$mix = json_encode($mix);

// Check the output
printf($mix);

/* Prints out:

{
  "array1":"{"type":"column", "valueField":".1.", "descriptionField":".11."}",
  "array2":"{"type":"column", "valueField":".2.", "descriptionField":".22."}"
}

*/
```

You can fiddle around with it in in this [SANDBOX](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/474606e601480a9e1afb57f3753ebacb30ae576c), have some fun with it.

Comment: @CostCare Not a problem. I'm glad I could help you out. :]